# Pass multiple parameters to rest API - Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to pass a JSON object to rest API, Or pass a multiple parameters to that API ? And how to read these parameters in Spring ? Lets assume that the url looks like the below examples :

Ex.1 `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/mno/objectKey?id=1&name=saif`

Is it valid to pass a JSON object like in the url below ?

Ex.2 `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/mno/objectKey/{"id":1, "name":"Saif"}`

Questions:

1) Is it possible to pass a JSON object to the url like in Ex.2?

2) How can we pass and parse the parameters in Ex.1?

I tried to write some methods to achieve my goal, but could not find the right solution?

I tried to pass JSON object as @RequestParam

`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/mno/objectKey?id=1` There was an unexpected error `(type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415). Content type 'null' not supported`

`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/mno/objectKey/id=1` There was an unexpected error `(type=Not Found, status=404). No message available`

`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/mno/objectKey/%7B%22id%22:1%7D` There was an unexpected error `(type=Not Found, status=404). No message available`

```
@RequestMapping(value="mno/{objectKey}",
                method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                consumes="application/json")
    public List<Book> getBook4(@RequestParam ObjectKey objectKey) {
        ...
    }
```

I tried to pass the JSON object as @PathVariable

```
@RequestMapping(value="ghi/{objectKey}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Book> getBook2(@PathVariable ObjectKey objectKey) {
        ...         
    }
```

I created this object to hold the id parameter and other parameters like name , etc ....

```
class ObjectKey{
        long id;
        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about annotation [@RequestBody](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) and passing object as body?

Comment: Any particular reason why you'd want to do it this way? You should be able to get an object out of the request that matches an entity.

Comment: Sorry if the example is not accurate, It is just a proof of concept, I want to be able to get list of suggested items from the DB based on a search criteria. I will have a widget that calls the rest API and pass the parameters . But I am trying to focus on the backend part at the moment

Answer (score 101, accepted):

> (1) Is it possible to pass a JSON object to the url like in Ex.2?

No, because `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/mno/objectKey/{"id":1, "name":"Saif"}` is not a valid URL.

If you want to do it the RESTful way, use `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/mno/objectKey/1/Saif`, and define your method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/mno/objectKey/{id}/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Book getBook(@PathVariable int id, @PathVariable String name) {
    // code here
}
```

> (2) How can we pass and parse the parameters in Ex.1?

Just add two request parameters, and give the correct path.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/mno/objectKey", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Book getBook(@RequestParam int id, @RequestParam String name) {
    // code here
}
```

**UPDATE** *(from comment)*

> What if we have a complicated parameter structure ?
>
> ```json
> "A": [ {
>     "B": 37181,
>     "timestamp": 1160100436,
>     "categories": [ {
>         "categoryID": 2653,
>         "timestamp": 1158555774
>     }, {
>         "categoryID": 4453,
>         "timestamp": 1158555774
>     } ]
> } ]
> ```

Send that as a `POST` with the JSON data in the request body, not in the URL, and specify a content type of `application/json`.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/mno/objectKey", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public Book getBook(@RequestBody ObjectKey objectKey) {
    // code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andreas , It works :) But I still have some question ? What if we have a complicated parameter structure ? ** "A": [  
          {  
               "B": 37181,  
               "timestamp": 1160100436,  
               "categories": [  
                    {  
                         "categoryID": 2653,  
                         "timestamp": 1158555774  
                    },  
                    {  
                         "categoryID": 4453,  
                         "timestamp": 1158555774  
                    }  
               ]  
          }  
     ] **

Comment: You don't send something like that in a `GET`, you use a `POST`, and include the JSON in the payload, specifying a content type of `application/json`.

Comment: Thanks for the last update Andreas, Is it possible to create a POST using JavaScript because I don't want to consume this rest API using a form , I wanted the JavaScript to consume it.

Comment: Yes. I'd suggest you do a web search. I'd also suggest using a library, such as `jQuery`, to make it easier.

Comment: Some people willl argue that you should not send a POST instead of a GET if you want to have a RESTful API. In simple words: POST is only to create data, PUT is to update, GET is to retrieve data

Comment: @jolumg The *some people* didn't read the [HTTP definition of the POST method](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.3): *"The POST method requests that the target resource **process** the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's **own specific semantics**"*. Sure, the most common semantic is for the resource to create something, but *process* is more generic and can mean other things, e.g. *run* a credit check using the supplied data. `GET` would be an inappropriate method for that.

Comment: @Andreas do I need to create deserializer classes to convert nested JSON into Java objects?

Comment: What if you want to pass multiple named complicated parameters? Such as @RequestBody (EntityOne, EntityTwo)

Comment: @Devin You mean like already shown in this answer below the **UPDATE** line? --- *FYI:* There can be only one `@RequestBody` parameter, so if you have multiple entities, then you need a parent object to contain them in that one-and-only object sent to the server.

Comment: I mean to deserialize objects dynamically into multiple parameters. You would have to build an alternative to @RequestBody that had knowledge of the possible request types. Probably too much overhead and too much effort. I just went with the wrapper solution

Answer (score 42):

you can pass multiple params in url like

http://localhost:2000/custom?brand=dell&limit=20&price=20000&sort=asc

and in order to get this query fields , you can use map like

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/custom")
    public String controllerMethod(@RequestParam Map<String, String> customQuery) {

        System.out.println("customQuery = brand " + customQuery.containsKey("brand"));
        System.out.println("customQuery = limit " + customQuery.containsKey("limit"));
        System.out.println("customQuery = price " + customQuery.containsKey("price"));
        System.out.println("customQuery = other " + customQuery.containsKey("other"));
        System.out.println("customQuery = sort " + customQuery.containsKey("sort"));

        return customQuery.toString();
    }
```

Comment: This really helped me in creating a GET service with dynamic URL params. Thanks @Om Sharma

Answer (score 2):

Multiple parameters can be given like below,

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/mno/{objectKey}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public List<String> getBook(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @PathVariable(name = "objectKey") String objectKey
      , @RequestParam(value = "id", defaultValue = "false")String id,@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "false") String name) throws Exception {
               //logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to pass JSON object in URL

```
queryString = "{\"left\":\"" + params.get("left") + "}";
 httpRestTemplate.exchange(
                    Endpoint + "/A/B?query={queryString}",
                    HttpMethod.GET, entity, z.class, queryString);
```