# GET request with body

Tags: rest, kotlin

In my last project I've done a controller like this one:

```
@GetMapping("/search")
fun findByUserContact(@RequestBody @Valid userContactDto: UserContactDto) =
    userService.findByUserContact(userContactDto)
```

An `UserContactDto` is:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Email::class, name = "email"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cellphone::class, name = "cellphone"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Both::class, name = "both")
)
sealed class UserContactDto

data class Email(@field:javax.validation.constraints.Email val email: String) : UserContactDto()
data class Cellphone(@field:PhoneNumber val cellphone: String) : UserContactDto()
data class Both(
    @field:javax.validation.constraints.Email val email: String,
    @field:PhoneNumber val cellphone: String
) : UserContactDto()
```

I've design the API in this way because I don't know if the search will be done through:

- email only
- cellphone only
- both email and cellphone

but I think that is not a good design for a REST API... a GET request with a body.
What could be a good approach to solve my use case?

Could a custom serializer *query params* -> `UserContact` be a valid approach?
Will it be cleaner to create different APIs for the 3 different cases?

Thanks,
Francesco

Comment: You might be able to figure out which of the three via a HTTP header like `user-agent` that came in the request

Answer (score 0):

I would argue you could with

1. Multiple query parameters (check approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38032635/pass-multiple-parameters-to-rest-api-spring))
2. Different apis
3. Current approach, using instead a POST (check this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body))